# Custom response for invalid token authentication in Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

For the following piece of code, I would like to return a boolean corresponding to whether the user was authenticated or not.

```
class UserAuthenticatedView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        is_authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated()
        resp = {'is_authenticated': is_authenticated}
        return Response(resp, content_type="application/json", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

However, for invalid token, the control is not not even going inside `get` method due to which I'm not able to customize the response. In such a case I'm getting the response: `{'detail': 'invalid token'}`,
Any idea on how to customize the response for invalid token ?

Comment: I think you should create a custom TokenAuthentication class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

Custom Authentication class:

```
class MyAuthentication(authentication.TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
        try:
            token = self.model.objects.select_related('user').get(key=key)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            return (None, '')

        if not token.user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('User inactive or deleted.'))

        return (token.user, token)
```

view class:

```
class UserAuthenticatedView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (MyAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        is_authenticated = False
        if request.user and request.user.is_authenticated():
            is_authenticated = True
        resp = {'is_authenticated': is_authenticated}
        return Response(resp, content_type="application/json", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: what is the point of requesting and checking token validity if you otherwise have an allow any

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `CustomTokenAuthentication` class and override the `authenticate_credentials()` method to return the custom response in case of invalid token.

```
class CustomTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):

    def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
        try:
            token = self.model.objects.select_related('user').get(key=key)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            # modify the original exception response
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Custom error message') 

        if not token.user.is_active:
            # can also modify this exception message
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User inactive or deleted')

        return (token.user, token)
```

After doing this, define this custom token authentication class in your DRF settings or on a per-view/viewset basis.

Another option is to create a [custom exception handler.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) In that, you can check if the exception raised was of type `AuthenticationFailed` and the exception message is `'invalid token'`. There you can modify the exception message (also check this official DRF [example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)).